# Unexpected token fix when sending data from google sheet to cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvdoU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y4u5.png)

Hi All,

Im receiving the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!' (line 49, file "updateFirestore.gs")

when trying to write data from google sheet to cloud firestore using google script. Within my cloud firestore document, i have a fixed attribute named as "!lk", as it has been used in the development of an app. In order to change this attribute name, I will have to change app code and resubmit to app store, basically a lot of work. is there any way I can use "!lk" without getting the unexpected token error in google script and have it successfully populate as an attribute in cloud firestore.

any help will be greatly appriciated! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If there's really a key **"!lk"** you want to send in post data, to assign it you need to use following syntax:

```
data['!lk'] = sourceData[i][9];
```